# bootstrap works locally but not when deployed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using MVC framework and bootstrap to optimize the website. Everything works locally but not on the server. The website has no css watsoever. Also the front page should be a carousel slider and now it's just all the pictures displayed in a vertical manner. What is the problem?

Here is my code:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - The Secured Password</title>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
```

Thanks!

EDITED:

Here is the rendered header:

```
<link href="/Content/css?v=UV-jZ4aDFGX-mj3fDEnMFNwudw9kdbZQj1zFCxtmgps1"   rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1">   </script><style type="text/css"></style>

<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1"></script>

<script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=HHeOtfpYTGpvkQWzPsmQOp39ZdG4zLSAsANOtnmyV-g1"></script>
```

Edited #2:
Here is the content for bundleconfig.cs:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Content/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Content/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Content/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Content/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Content/CSS/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/CSS/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/CSS/Site.css"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Which framework you are using?

Comment: Can you show us the rendered header code as well?

Comment: I'm using MVC framwork

Comment: FYI, *MVC* is an acronym for *Model / View / Controller*. You are using the ASP.NET MVC Framework.

Comment: Lesson learned, thanks Phil!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing there to render Bootstrap's own css files (bootstrap[.min].css and bootstrap-theme[.min].css).

Comment: So how do i fix that? I'm sure those files are on the server, its just not rendering it.

Comment: Check the contents (hehe) of your `Content` folder. Something seems messed up there, since your `<link>` isn't rendering right. Those two files should be in there, as well as any CSS you (or Visual Studio) created. See if you can successfully run the "movie" application from http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction, which uses Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's fixed. I simply changed the cshtml code:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

part to be normal html code as

```
<script src="/bundles/bootstrap.css"></script>
```

Not much a solution but it solved my problem.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: That's not going to work if you change the location of your app (like putting it in a sub-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Is bootstrap.css included in your "~/Content/css" bundle? Check your BundleConfig.cs RegisterStyleBundles function to see if you've properly included the bootstrap css in that bundle, since you aren't rendering any other style bundles, if it isn't included in that bundle properly then that would certainly explain why you weren't getting the css.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i checked BundleConfig and they r in there.

Comment: But that doesn't tell us whether or not something is wrong with the way you have it included. Could you maybe show us your BundleConfig.cs?